# Deliberately creating unbalanced class size

Tags: logistic, unbalanced-classes, medicine

I'm working on a logistic regression model to predict a certain disease, binary classification (Present/Not_Present). The disease has a normal occurrence rate of about 10% in the general population. However, the way in which my dataset has been created I have almost 50/50 class split.

Naturally, this is ideal in terms of building a model, but i'm worried about generalization of the final model.

However, when the model is pushed into production it won't be dealing with the general population. People who are evaluated by the model will have a high probability of having the disease.

Note: I plan on using the Youden J Index & ROC to find a cut off point estimate.

Comment: Can you get an estimate of the overall prior probability of having the desease in the population to which the model has been applied?  If so, the method of King and Zeng will be useful: https://gking.harvard.edu/files/abs/0s-abs.shtml

Comment: Haha thanks! In my current model the overall prior is .65. As I said above, the Prevalence is .10. I'l read that paper and see if it helps :)